# How to use Variables in Automator

Tags: variables, workflow, automator

please bear with me, I use Automator since not long.

I have good experience in PHP (totally different) and some small scripting knowledge (apple script, shell, etc).

I try to replicate this logic workflow with Automator:

1. Ask User to insert value (set $variable_a)
2. Ask User to insert one more value (set $variable_b)
3. Submit
4. This triggers a script that uses both values submitted above. A dummy example:

   echo $variable_a
   echo variable_b

Seems simple, and it's amazing how fast you can set up this logic with Automator.

The problem is, at stage 2 above, my `$variable_a` is suddenly a mixed value of `$variable_a` and `$variable_b`.

Why does this happen?

They do not seem to act as I understand the generic usage of "variables" in any language or programming step.
In other systems, usually, variables keep as value what they got defined (unless variable variables or you modify them consciously in the code)

I attached an [Automator "WorkFlow" File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vUlMivDmeSdKlFRDGYpZcjDD8x5PExbK) that replicates exactly the abovementioned WorkFlow Logic. 
It's a ZIP file, unzip it and open in Automator for a test.

You will see (in the results section for the last step) how the values become (IMHO) false.

Has someone a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the output of one action in the workflow is being fed as input into the next action of the workflow.  As inputs are received by actions, they can also aggregate in some cases, such as when setting and getting variables.

The reason it does this is so that you could sent multiple variables directly into, say, a **Run Shell Script** action, and references them using `$1`, `$2`, etc.  If *Automator* only ever took the most recent input, you'd never be able to feed more than one variable into a shell script without first combining them manually yourself into a list.

The solution is simple.  Every action has an **Options** button that you can press, which in turn reveals a checkbox called **Ignore this action's input**.  This needs to be checked for those actions that you want to operate independently of previous results.

Here's a screenshot of your workflow with the appropriate checkboxes ticked against the actions that require it:

[image: Automator Workflow]

Comment: First I thought, this will never work... looking closer, it made sense

Tried it, and seems to be the right solution

Both variables now have the correct, previously set value

BTW; "a Run Shell Script action, and references them using $1, $2, etc", this is exactly what I want

but, with my setup, in the shell $@ you will have a complete mess.

I will now check what your approach produces in $@ and $f

Thanks a lot, accepted answer as it solves the reported problem.

Comment: @smileBeda The way to achieve the variable references in a **Run Shell Script** action is to insert a series of **Get Value of Variable** actions directly before it: i.e. *Get variable > Get variable > ... > Run Shell Script*.  You want to pass the input **as arguments**.  Then, what was an inconvenience for you before is now your blessing, as all of those variable actions preceding the shell script will aggregate into a list, which gets delivered as arguments to the shell script that can be referenced `$1`, `$2`, etc., and `$@`.